# Proving $\iint_R f(x,y)\,dA\geq \iint_R g(x,y)\,dA$, when $f(x,y) \geq g(x,y)$ for every $(x,y) \in R$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

I don't know how to prove the following claim.

> If $f(x,y) \geq g(x,y)$ for every $(x,y) \in R$, then prove that
> $$\iint_R f(x,y)\,dA\geq \iint_R g(x,y)\,dA$$
> using the following properties
>
> (i) $$\iint_R cf(x,y)dA=c\iint_R f(x,y)dA$$ for every real number $c$
>
> (ii) $$\iint_R [f(x,y) + g(x,y)]dA = \iint_R f(x,y)dA + \iint_R g(x,y)dA$$
>
> (iii) if $R$ is the union of $r_1$ and $r_2$ and they don't overlap then
>
> $$\iint_R f(x,y)dA = \iint_{r_1} f(x,y)dA + \iint_{r_2} f(x,y)dA$$
>
> (iv) if $f(x,y)\geq 0$ in a region $R$ then:
> $$\iint_R f(x,y)dA \geq 0$$

I tried to refer to $f(x,y)$ as $g(x,y) + h(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)\geq 0$
and then subtitute:

$$\iint_R f(x,y)dA = \iint_R g(x,y) + h(x,y)dA= \iint_R g(x,y)dA + \iint_R h(x,y)dA $$
then
$$\iint_R g(x,y)dA + \iint_R h(x,y)dA \geq \iint_R g(x,y)dA$$

But I don't know if is correctly proven, is the logic correct? I know is a dumb proof but how can I be sure?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: okey thanks i guess XD, also, is asking this type of questions (lf something is correct) against the guidelines?

Comment: It's not against the guidelines, you can moreover add the solution-verification tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is good, but I'll rewrite it a  little more simply. We have
$$
\iint f \  dA=\iint (f-g) \ dA+\iint g \ dA
$$
by (ii). But
$$
\iint (f-g) \ dA \ge 0
$$
by (iv). Therefore
$$
\iint f \ dA \ge \iint g \ dA. 
$$

Comment: yeah i thought that it was bad if i integrate f = f-g+g but that seems good haha